# Storing Tables of Information on the Android Platform

Tags: android, sqlite

I have about twenty pages of information that is stored in tables that needs to be stored in my Android application. Each column is a designated stop on a bus route and the column is filled with times that the bus will be at the stop. There is also certain information that needs to be associated with some times, such as if the bus is handicap accessible at a certain time.

Here is an example of one of the tables: [Bus Times](http://www.cyride.com/routes/Summer/WDRedEast.html)

I have thought about using a SQL lite as that seems as though it would be able to store these tables quite easily; but when I think of using SQL I think of dynamic data storage and this shouldn't be changing more than once a year.

Is SQL appropriate for this application? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks, 
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a database is really the appropriate form for doing this. Data in a database don't have to chance regularly or very often, almost more important is the fact that you can relatively easy extract very specific information from a large data set. So if you need to store the data lcoally I would use a database.

Just a hint for another approach. Did you think about reading this data directly from the website? Judging from the style of this page I don't think they offer a webservice, but maybe you could parse it using HTTP Get? Don't know if the structure changes over time, but this solution would have the advantage that you don't need locale storage and if the data is update you don't have to manually update your database.

Hope could help you

Comment: I definitely have thought about  pulling it directly from the website but the formatting tends to be a little different page to page and it does tend to change a little bit over time. 

Thanks for the input on using a database.

Comment: Also when you say database are you referring to SQL lite that is available? Or are there other databases I could use with a Android application?

Comment: i was talking about sql lite. don't know if there would be another one.